# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap error when trying to execute tests using Chromedriver and Maven

Tags: java, selenium, maven, selenium-webdriver, nosuchmethoderror

I am new to selenium tests and I am currently watching some youtube videos using maven.

Today I tried a few codes and worked fine but when accessing one store page and trying to search a product it gives me "Access Denied" message
So I tried a few ways to open chrome instead of chromedriver.

But I gave up and was willing to try another webpage. But now chromedriver wont open (gives error message). operadriver, geckodriver and etc will immediately close after launch.

I am getting this error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap.of(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object)'
```

I tried looking in a lot of places but most said it was guava version, I dont use guava, even though I tried adding it to dependencies...

My code is this:

```
public class TestYoutubeClass {
    WebDriver driver;
    @Before
    public void runDriver(){
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("http://www.kabum.com.br");
```

I tried starting from the beginning and nothing worked.
I am using IntelliJ
On `pom.xml` I added: `junit; selenium-java` and `webdrivermanager`.

Every help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 17):

The issue comes from conflicting Guava (transitive dependency) versions.

It should be fixed with the [WebDriverManager version 5.1.0](https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#removed).

As an alternative, you can also use the `<dependencyManagement>` section of your `pom.xml` to *force* a resolution of the latest Guava version:

```
<dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
      <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
      <version>31.0.1-jre</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

or exclude the Guava dependency from the WebDriverManager (no longer required for >= 5.1.0):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
    <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.3</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

PS: To ensure dependency convergence for your Maven project, consider adding the Maven Enforcer Plugin [to detect multiple versions](https://rieckpil.de/top-3-maven-plugins-to-ensure-quality-and-security-for-your-project/) of the transitive dependency early on.

Comment: Only adding to the <dependencyManagement> section solved the issue for me

Comment: I used the second method you posted, adding the block to the same pom.xml that contains the org.selenium.hq dependencies. Rebuilt and did a clean maven install. No change. Still fails with java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap

Comment: I suggest adding `<scope>test</scope>` to the dependency.

Answer (score 14):

I'm using maven and downgraded Version 4.1.2 to 4.1.1 solved my problem

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: What version of webdrivermanager are you using?

Comment: ma man !!!!!!!!!

Comment: this version is very old now. which version should we use today ?

Answer (score 9):

I also faced the above issue after adding below dependency it worked fine. I am using Chrome 98 version

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
      <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
      <version>31.0.1-jre</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

Comment: updating the guava version helped me resolve the issue! thanks

Answer (score 3):

Just add

```
    workbook.close();
```

Or try this code in your pom.xml, it works for me

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>31.0.1-jre</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
        <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the master branch of Guava today, it looks like the actual issue is simply that no version of `com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap.of(...)` accepts more than 10 parameters (the thread starter's error shows 12). It is documented in the source code here:

https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava/src/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableMap.java

This is the comment after the version that accepts 10 entries:
`// looking for of() with > 10 entries? Use the builder or ofEntries instead.`

I am suggesting the usage of .of() in Selenium is changed to on of the suggested methods in the copied comment above since this seems to be a recurring issue for a lot of people.

Will try to re-open this issue to get this taken care of:
https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/10324

Answer (score 2):

This error message...

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap.of(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object)'
```

...implies that there is *NoSuchMethod* as `com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap` which indicates it might be corrupted or there is some incompatibility between the version of the binaries you are using specifically with the **guava** *version* / *dependency* (maven).

---

You need to take care of a couple of things as follows:

- You need to add the `System.setProperty()`:

  ```
  System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jre1.8.0_231\\lib\\ext\\geckodriver.exe");
  ```
- Use only a single instance of WebDriver, either from the *class* scope or from the *method* scope.
- Effectively, you line of code will be;

  ```
  public class TestYoutubeClass {
      WebDriver driver;
      @Before
      public void runDriver(){
          System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","/path/to/chromedriver");
          driver = new ChromeDriver();
          driver.get("http://www.kabum.com.br");
  ```
- Incase you are using [maven](/questions/tagged/maven) deleting the corrupt/incompatible `.m2` folder can solve your issue.

Answer (score 2):

Theres seems to be a bug in 5.0.x versions of webdrivermanager, see last two messages in this thread - https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager/issues/576

Try switching the webdrivermanager dependency version to 4.4.3, worked for me.

Comment: there's been an update to webdrivermanager, looks like this issue is fixed in version 5.1.0 now.

Answer (score 2):

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>31.0.1-jre</version>
    </dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.github.bonigarcia/webdrivermanager  -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
    <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.0</version>
</dependency>
I used above version in pom.xml.This will help me to come out of this error.
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Maven pom.xml file then
check the version of the WebDriverManager below 5.1.0 .
I used the below version

> (5.1.0)

to solve the shown issue!

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
    <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

use version version 4.1.1

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have personally solved these with these versions:

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <spring.boot.version>1.5.21.RELEASE</spring.boot.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
        <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Comment: What solved it? You're posting a bunch of versions, but not a solution?

Comment: To solved this error (java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap error when trying to execute tests using Chromedriver and Maven) I have change the versions of my dependencies. With these versions I no longer have the above error

Answer (score 0):

Spend another 3 hours fighting with selenium.

That worked for me:

```
    <selenium.version>4.1.2</selenium.version>
    <selenium-webdrivermanager.version>5.0.1</selenium-webdrivermanager.version>
    <guava.version>31.0.1-jre</guava.version>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>${selenium.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-leg-rc</artifactId>
        <version>${selenium.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
                <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-api</artifactId>
        <version>${selenium.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
        <version>${selenium.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-remote-driver</artifactId>
        <version>${selenium.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-support</artifactId>
        <version>${selenium.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
        <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
        <version>${selenium-webdrivermanager.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>${guava.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: `<guava.version>31.0.1-jre</guava.version>` is the crucial part.

Answer (score 0):

It solved while I am using this dependency.
Use selenium 4.1.1 version.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).